# Musical star or music star?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, difference

Which of these expressions is/are correct?

- Music star
- Musical star

As in:

- He is a bright music star.
- He is a bright musical star.

Comment: They have different meanings.

Answer (score 3):

When we talk about a prominent or popular performer in some entertainment area, (a 'star'),  e.g. music, film/movie, radio, TV, we use the name of the area, e.g. a TV star, a film star, a radio etc, not an adjective such as 'musical'.

Furthermore, when talking about stars in music, we tend to specify the type of music, e.g. pop star, rock star, jazz star, hip-hop star, country [music] star.

If we say that someone is a 'musical star', we would probably be understood to be talking about someone who was a star of [stage] musicals, such as Annie Get Your Gun, Funny Girl, Cabaret, South Pacific, Oklahoma! etc.

Comment: Very well put, I do say.

Comment: What about musicals? Hugh Jackman is one the great musical stars in  "The Music Man".

Comment: Thank you for your input.